# Array filter function not calling to check for duplicates

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to filter my array:

```
case ON_SET_RECENT_SEARCH: {
  const searchToSave = action.payload;


  const filteredSearches = state.recentSearches.filter(

    // function to check for duplicates - pass in current item and searchToSave to check against

    !checkForDuplicate(item, searchToSave),
  );


  return {
   ...
  };
}
```

checkForDuplicate function, `console.log` never gets called. How can I filter my array using my helper function?

```
const checkForDuplicate = (item, searchToSave) => {
  console.log('checkForDuplicate');
  const isDuplicate =
    (item.id === searchToSave.id &&
      item.fuelType === searchToSave.fuelType &&
      item.searchDistance === searchToSave.searchDistance) ||
    (!!item.isCurrentLocation && !!searchToSave.isCurrentLocation);

  return !isDuplicate;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `filter()` method of Array instances receives a callback as the parameter and you were passing `!checkForDuplicate(item, searchToSave)` which is a value (the `checkForDuplicate()` is executed and returns a value before the `filter()` is executed). Just need to update it as

```js
state.recentSearches.filter((item) => !checkForDuplicate(item, searchToSave));
```

Read more from [the Array.prototype.filter() docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 0):

The parameter to `.filter()` should be an function like below.

```
state.recentSearches.filter(item => !checkForDuplicate(item, searchToSave));
```